# Java В Spring после добавления addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) в класс class MvcConfig - перестал работать обычный @Controller

Tags: java, spring, mvc, controller, boot

Пытаюсь по урокам и гайдам с сайта сделать спринг приложение с авторизацией/регистрацией , и там везде указано,что через addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) в класс class MvcConfig делается. Но до этого был GreetingController , который просто отображал мне страницу /greeting , теперь же через контроллер он не работает - ошибка Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

и новые Mapping-и не получается сделать , даже чтоб просто что-то простое отобразило. Авторизация работает нормально. Как сделать чтоб контроллер работал вместе с addViewControllers? [![структура1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfrgU.jpg)

```
package com.examples.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication

public class BdApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BdApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/personal_Area").setViewName("personal_Area");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }
}
```

```
package com.examples.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                            .requestMatchers("/","/greeting").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .formLogin((form) -> form
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .permitAll()
                    )
                    .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            UserDetails user =
                    User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username("user")
                            .password("password")
                            .roles("USER")
                            .build();

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        }
    }
```

Котроллер:

```
package com.examples.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
         return "greeting";
}


}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello world!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все таки спринг - это бэкенд фреймворк, и для отображения в браузере форм он в реальной жизни не используется. В целом вскорее всего во ViewControllerRegistry вам надо добавить и ваш существующий контроллер greeting

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте ссылку на используемый ресурс.